# Longest substring that doesn't match a REGEX pattern

Tags: python, regex

I'm preparing for an exam, and here's the task:
Given a string which consists of uppercase letters of English alphabet, find the longest substring of it, which doesn't contain `QW` or `WQ`.

I know I could do `re.split` or something like that, but I made it a challenge for me to do it with a *"regex matching"* expression like `len(max(re.findall(...), key=len))` **without** using `split` or other methods. Is it even possible?

To find *all* matching subtrings, I tried this:

```
list(map(lambda x: x[0], re.findall(r'(((?<!QW|WQ).)+(?!QW|WQ))', text))
```

But this **does** match a substring which *ends* with `WQ`, for example. How do I fix this?

Let me also clarify something. Let's say the string is `WQABCDEFGHQW`. The answer in this case is `QABCDEFGHQ`, as this is exactly *the longest substring that doesn't contain `WQ` or `QW`*.

Comment: You can use finditer instead of findall and reference the appropriate group in the match object.

Comment: In `abcQWz` it should find `abcQ` or `abc` only ?

Comment: abcq does match. (as there's no wq or qw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.?(?:.(?<!QW|WQ))*
```

Any single character is ok. Any further character is ok unless it creates QW or WQ.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CB2RTK/1)

Python demo along with two split-solutions:

```
input:   'AQWBQWC':
find:   ['AQ', 'WBQ', 'WC', '']
split1: ['AQ', 'WBQ', 'WC']
split2: ['AQ', 'WBQ', 'WC']

input:   'AQWBWQC':
find:   ['AQ', 'WBW', 'QC', '']
split1: ['AQ', 'WBW', 'QC']
split2: ['AQ', 'WBW', 'QC']

input:   '':
find:   ['']
split1: ['']
split2: ['']

input:   'A':
find:   ['A', '']
split1: ['A']
split2: ['A']

input:   'Q':
find:   ['Q', '']
split1: ['Q']
split2: ['Q']

input:   'QW':
find:   ['Q', 'W', '']
split1: ['Q', 'W']
split2: ['Q', 'W']
```

(The extra empty matches don't matter, just like other non-longest matches don't matter. Will get discarded by your `max(..., key=len)`.)

Code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/LCsIwEEX3/YpxNRktAetGgqWoX5BV1oIVAzUNaVwI/feaRwVfs5i5d@5hYOzDX3uz2Vo3Tfpme@fBtUVx0eYMUIND3rBGcNbsFlKNShItsRhsp/06xSGoJbGmVjRGraKWNDPVzNQ8cfkAhvO9gwG0AdxLdZDqiGWWSiaZbGwyNYWigFDWaeMZamPvXgCEzLXWsYFgBSiQ3qH4wYvh0Zy6jsVZwkAfZP5GZDIZllf/yeqXrL5JmqYn)):

```
import re

find  = r'.?(?:.(?<!QW|WQ))*'
split1 = r'(?<=Q)(?=W)|(?<=W)(?=Q)'
split2 = r'(?=.(?<=QW|WQ))'

for s in 'AQWBQWC', 'AQWBWQC', '', 'A', 'Q', 'QW':
    print('input:  ', repr(s) + ':')
    print('find:  ', re.findall(find, s))
    print('split1:', re.split(split1, s))
    print('split2:', re.split(split2, s))
    print()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
(?:[A-Z](?<!QW|WQ)(?<!Q(?=W)|W(?=Q)))+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7iowgp/1).

*Details*:

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `[A-Z]` - an uppercase ASCII letter
  - `(?<!QW|WQ)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if, immediately on the left, there is a `QW` or `WQ` substring (i.e. if the `[A-Z]` matched `W` (preceded with `Q`) or `Q` (preceded with `W`))
  - `(?<!Q(?=W)|W(?=Q))` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if, immediately on the left, there is a `Q` immediately followed with `W`, or `W` that is immediately followed with `Q` (i.e. if `[A-Z]` matched `Q` and the next char is `W`, or if `[A-Z]` matches `W` and the next char is `Q`)
- `)+` - end of the group, one or more occurrences.

Another approach:

```
(?:(?!QW|WQ)[A-Z](?<!QW|WQ))+
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7iowgp/2). *Details*:

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `(?!QW|WQ)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately on the right, there is a `QW` or `WQ` substring
  - `[A-Z]` - an uppercase ASCII letter
  - `(?<!QW|WQ)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if, immediately on the left, there is a `QW` or `WQ` substring
- `)+` - end of the group, one or more occurrences.

Comment: Thanks! but I still don't get it. For example, why is a lookbehind after another lookbehind which is after a character set pattern? And how are those lookbehinds different? `(?<!Q(?=W)|W(?=Q))` vs `(?<!WQ|QW)`). And I heard that lookbehinds in the end of the pattern are useless, or working incorrectly, or something else is wrong with them... How do they even work [in the end of the group]? When you put it before a character, let's say, the engine looks for the character and checks the lookbehind, but in this case what does it look for before checking the lookbehind?

Comment: @Wynell I explained how the pattern works in the answer. The lookbehinds are different. Placing them at the end makes sense, it makes the pattern efficient. Additional read for you: [Lookarounds Stand their Ground](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#stand_their_ground) and [Positioning the Lookaround](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#position).

Comment: Your first regex demo shows that you find three matches of length 3, but actually "WDEFW" is the correct answer.

Comment: @Wynell Do my solutions work for you?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew I didn't try that yet. I tried the simplest one, from another answer. From @Kelly Bundy's comment I see that you only match substrings that doesn't contain even single `Q`-s and `W`-s, which are parts of `WQ` or `QW`. Even though it's quite not what I looked for, this is still a relevant answer for a similar question. And still interesting to look into. Don't delete it or erase the current content, please.

Answer (score 1):

You could use that: `(?:(?!WQ|QW).(?<!WQ|QW))+`
At each position (of the dot) it tests forward and backward if the character isn't a part of WQ or QW.

The key is to test forward before the dot and backward after the dot position.

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/98y8CO/1)

---

Other possible pattern: `(?:.(?!.?(?<=WQ|QW)))+`

This time a lookbehind is inside a negative lookahead but since it is preceded by an optional character `.?`, it checks the two possible positions of the WQ/QW sequence.

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/AM8pjU/1)

---

Or to reduce the number of steps an unrolled pattern:
`[^WQ]+(?:[QW](?!.?(?<=QW|WQ))[^WQ]*)*|(?:[QW](?!.?(?<=QW|WQ))[^WQ]*)+`

But it's a bit long (it's unrolled).

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/dkovHe/1)

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
(?:(?!Q(?!W)|(?<!W)Q).)+
```

##### Python Example

```
import re

s = "HAKSDUWQHUPHPSAHFPUAHPUSNFJHJWQHPJQWPHJWQWASDIAS"
print(max(re.findall(r"(?:(?!Q(?!W)|(?<!W)Q).)+", s), key=len))  # 'HUPHPSAHFPUAHPUSNFJHJW'
```

See the regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fIrRtD/1)

Comment: it would match ABCSLWPQW (as everything before the last character `W` also doesn't match `QW`, because it's actually `PQ`)

Comment: Try with [`(?:(?!Q(?!W)|(?<!W)Q).)+`](https://regex101.com/r/fIrRtD/1)

Comment: @KellyBundy, No I do. See [this](https://regex101.com/r/UZDqkx/1)

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. For "AQWBQWC" you don't find "WBQ".